# Using Luigi package to create and run tasks

Tags: python, luigi

I am trying to follow the Luigi-Jupyter tutorial
link: [Luigi Tutorial](https://intoli.com/blog/luigi-jupyter-notebooks/)

I have managed to set up my environment but struggling with adding the first task to my pipeline.

I used nano file.py to create a python file and added the following code:

```
import os
import luigi

output_path = '/Users/mattiaciollaro/Git/luigi_tutorial/output/'

class TellMeMyName(luigi.Task):
    """
    An incredibly simple task that writes your name to a text file.
    """
    my_name = luigi.Parameter()

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget(
            os.path.join(output_path, 'my_name.txt')
        )

    def run(self):
        with open(self.output().path, 'w') as out:
            out.write('Your name is %s' % self.my_name)
```

I then try and run this on my terminal using:
    python file.py

However I cannot seem to be able to run the task (I'm assuming maybe I am not supposed to write the code in a file?)

This is what I run on terminal:

```
luigi --module tasks file.py TellMeMyName --my-name Emmanuel
```

and I get this error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tasks'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the python path before (note "." for MacOS):

```
PYTHONPATH='.' luigi --module file TellMeMyName --my-name Emmanuel
```

.. then make sure the central scheduler is configured:

https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/central_scheduler.html

This discussion should help you along:

https://github.com/spotify/luigi/issues/1321

Answer (score 0):

From the tutorial you linked:

> All of the tasks presented in this post are in the repository’s tasks.py file. >If you are using the companion repository, there is no need to copy and paste: >the tasks in tasks.py are ready to run.

Your script you said is called file.py, if you remove the 'tasks' module from what you're trying to run on terminal it should run. Something like:

```
luigi --module file TellMeMyName --my-name Emmanuel
```

Comment: I get the error message 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file''